# How to edit the position of a banner text's pointer?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine, wpf

I have build an ITool where one can add text (`ITextElement`) to the map. The user can choose the symbol from the ESRI symbology. There one can choose a symbol called "Banner Text" which looks like this in the preview:

[image: Banner Text Symbol Preview]

When one adds the text with this symbol, only the rectangle is shown without the 'pointer'. How can I edit this pointer? I didn't find any information about it. Maybe I'm simply missing the right name or search phrase for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ArcObjects? Set the callout's [`AnchorPoint`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w0000008w000000) property to an `IPoint` at the desired map coordinates.

VB example here: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=303569#949615

Answer (score 0):

When you select it with the cursor there will be 4 corner "blue boxes" or grips.
And one grip located elsewhere ussually in the box by default.
That is the grip you want to pull to the location
[image]